# How do i use a php cookie in an SQL select query

Tags: php, cookies

good day, i have an html form which takes user input and stores it in a cookie so i want to know how can i use that cookie in an SQL select query for instance like `" SELECT prescription FROM medications WHERE prescription LIKE '%$prescription%'";` and instead of that prescription variable i use the cookie value.

here is how i created the cookies

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['searchdisease'], $_POST['prescription'])) {
      setcookie('searchdisease', $_POST['searchdisease']);
       setcookie('prescription', $_POST['prescription']);
} 
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>INVOICE SUMMARY</legend>
    <input id="nol" type="text" style="width: 280px;" name="searchdisease" placeholder="Type a disease keyword">
    <input id="nol" type="text" style="width: 280px;" name="prescription" placeholder="Type a medication/procedure/service keyword">
    <button id="nol" class="SearchButton1" type="submit" name="submit" style="width: 100px; background-color:green; color: white;">SEARCH</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: You can get the `cookie` value like this: `$_COOKIE['prescription']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_COOKIE['prescription']`, but PLEASE read up on mysql injections and how to prevent them using prepared statements. Or at least add some other form of cleaning the value. Otherwise, you will open your application up to hacking because cookie contents can be tampered with using browser dev tools.

Comment: thank you for your quick sugesstions, and yes i will do that

when i do it like this 

$fetch_medication = " SELECT prescription FROM medications WHERE prescription LIKE '%$_COOKIE['prescription']%'";

the page dies

Comment: `$fetch_medication = " SELECT prescription FROM medications WHERE prescription LIKE '%" .  $_COOKIE['prescription'].  "%'";`

Comment: thanks but for some reason the query is fetching everything from the database not only where there is the cookie value

Comment: Did you check that the cookie value is correctly set? `var_dump($_COOKIE['prescription'])`

Comment: yeah i did, but now i have another issue, that submit button is not working

Comment: It's best not to append other issues to one question, but as it's simple: You have not supplied the action attribute on the form.

Comment: okay.. i will open another question

but i have set the method and action on the form im working on, not the above form